# Expanding 8-bit color to 24-bit color

Tags: algorithm, colors, arduino

### Setup

I have a couple hundred Sparkfun LED pixels (similar to https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11020) connected to an Arduino Uno and want to control the pixels from a PC using the built-in Serial-over-USB connection of the Arduino.

The pixels are individually adressable, each has 24 bits for the color (RGB). Since I want to be able to change the color of each pixel very quickly, the transmission of the data from the pc to the Arduino has to be very efficient (the further transmission of data from the Arduino to the pixels is very fast already).

### Problem

I've tried simply sending the desired RGB-Values directly as is to the Arduino but this leads to a visible delay, when I want to for example turn on all LEDs at the same time. My straightforward idea to minimize the amount of data is to reduce the available colors from 24-bit to 8-bit, which is more than enough for my application.

If I do this, I have to expand the 8-bit values from the PC to 24-bit values on the Arduino to set the actual color on the pixels. The obvious solution here would be a palette that holds all available 8-bit values and the corresponding 24-bit colors. I would like to have a solution without a palette though, mostly for memory space reasons.

### Question

What is an efficient way to expand a 8-bit color to a 24-bit one, preferrably one that preserves the color information accurately? Are there standard algorithms for this task?

### Possible solution

I was considering a format with 2 bits for each R and B and 3 bits for G. These values would be packed into a single byte that would be transmitted to the Arduino and then be unpacked using bit-shifting and interpolated using the map() function (http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map).

Any thoughts on that solution? What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Your 2-3-2 scheme is actually kind of palette. Color palette is the general way. The problem is that every image has its optimal color palette, and using one universal palette significantly reduces display quality.

Comment: If your images are relatively static, you can precompute optimal color palette and use it, possibly with acceptable quality.

Comment: what are you using to drive the arduino through serial? Processing, java, something else?

Comment: I am using a custom Java application that translates Midi signals to control signals that are then sent to the arduino.
I'm not trying to display images, it's LEDs on a string.

Comment: The performance of the USB-Serial link has a lot to do with driver settings in windows. Look into that first. Controlling a few LEDs should not take much bandwidth. Also make sure to write all the data in one output call.

Comment: what library are you using in Java? If you are using rxtx, this might be useful to you: http://neophob.com/2011/04/serial-latency-teensy-vs-arduino/

Answer (score 1):

R2B2G3 would give you very few colors (there's actually one more bit left). I don't know if it would be enough for your application. You can use [dithering technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) to make 8-bit images look a little better.

Alternatively, if you have any preferred set of colors, you can store known palette on your device and never send it over the wire. You can also store multiple palettes for different situations and specify which one to use with small integer index.

On top of that it's possible to implement some simple compression algorithm like [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) or [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) and decompress after receiving.

And there are some very fast compression libraries with small footprint you can use: [Snappy](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/), [miniLZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/#minilzo).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question “What would be a better way to do this?”, one of the first things to do (if not yet done) is increase the serial data rate. An [Arduino Forum](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,115557.0.html) suggests using 115200 bps as a standard rate, and trying 230400 bps.  At those rates you would need to write the receiving software so it quickly transfers data from the relatively small receive buffer into a larger buffer, instead of trying to work on the data out of the small receive buffer.

A second possibility is to put activation times into your data packets.  Suppose F1, F2, F3... are a series of frames you will display on the LED array.  Send those frames from the PC ahead of time, or during idle or wait times, and let the Arduino buffer them until they are scheduled to appear.  When the activation time arrives for a given frame, have the Arduino turn it on.  If you know in advance the frames but not the activation times, send and buffer the frames and send just activation codes at appropriate times.

Third, you can have multiple palettes and dynamic palettes that change on the fly and can use pixel addresses or pixel lists as well as pixel maps.  That is, you might use different protocols at different times.  Protocol 3 might download a whole palette, 4 might change an element of a palette, 5 might send a 24-bit value v, a time t, a count n, and a list of n pixels to be set to v at time t, 6 might send a bit map of pixel settings, and so forth.  Bit maps can be simple 1-bit-per-pixel maps indicating on or off, or can be k-bits-per-pixel maps, where a k-bit entry could specify a palette number or a frame number for a pixel.  This is all a bit vague because there are so many possibilities; but in short, define protocols that work well with whatever you are displaying.

Fourth, given the ATmega328P's small (2KB) RAM but larger (32KB) flash memory, consider hard-coding several palettes, frames, and macros into the program.  By macros, I mean routines that generate graphic elements like arcs, lines, open or filled rectangles.  Any display element that is known in advance is a candidate for flash instead of RAM storage.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comment. I will try increasing the data rate even further, but ideally the system will work under low bps-conditions as well. As for the pre-buffered frames, I am afraid that the tiny amount of RAM on the Arduino (2k iirc), won't be able to buffer all that much.

Comment: @user643813, added a paragraph re that.  But if you can buffer 2 frames and use time-codes, that allows sending data in the background, invisibly, vs with visible jerkiness due to USB timing idiosyncracies.

Answer (score 0):

Your (2, 3, 2) bit idea is used "in the wild."  It should be extremely simple to try out.  The quality will be pretty low, but try it out and see if it meets your needs.

It seems unlikely that any other solution could save much memory compared to a 256-color lookup table, if the lookup table stays constant over time.  I think anything successful would have to exploit a pattern in the kind of images you are sending to the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Any way you look at it, what you're really going for is image compression.  So, I would recommend looking at the likes of PNG and JPG compression, to see if they're fast enough for your application.

If not, then you might consider rolling your own.  There's only so far you can go with per-pixel compression; size-wise, your (2,3,2) idea is about as good as you can expect to get.  You could try a quadtree-type format instead:  take the average of a 4-pixel block, transmit a compressed (lossy) representation of the differences, then apply the same operation to the half-resolution image of averages...

As others point out, dithering will make your images look better at (2,3,2).  Perhaps the easiest way to dither for your application is to choose a different (random or quasi-random) fixed quantization threshold offset for each color of each pixel.  Both the PC and the Arduino would have a copy of this threshold table; the distribution of thresholds would prevent posterization, and the Arduino-side table would help maintain accuracy.